# Export HP ALM test plan to an excel file

Tags: excel, hp-alm

Is it possible to export HP ALM test plan cases to an excel file ?
I found some Add-INS that Export to HP ALM from excel.

Thanks for any advices..

Comment: Can you run a query in the database? If yes, I have a query I can give you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ALM, you can generate an Excel Report using the below SQL query. This should resolve the issue.

```
SELECT
  TEST.TS_TEST_ID as "Test ID", /*Test.Test ID*/
  TEST.TS_NAME as "Test Name", /*Test.Test Name*/
  TEST.TS_DESCRIPTION as "Test Desc.", /*Test.Description*/
  DESSTEPS.DS_STEP_NAME as "Step Name", /*Design Step.Step Name*/
  DESSTEPS.DS_DESCRIPTION as "Step Desc.", /*Design Step.Description*/
  DESSTEPS.DS_EXPECTED as "Expected Result", /*Design Step.Expected Result*/
  TEST.TS_STATUS as "Test Status", /*Test.Status*/
  TEST.TS_TYPE "Test Type", /*Test.Type*/
  TEST.TS_RESPONSIBLE as "Test Designer", /*Test.Designer*/
  TEST.TS_USER_03 as "Test Priority", /*Test.Priority*/
  TEST.TS_USER_04 as "Test Reviewer" /*Test.Reviewer*/
FROM
  Test,
  DESSTEPS  
WHERE
  DS_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
```

Comment: Any other alternative solution do you have to extract the data ? AS we don't have database access.